# What does App Engine do to prevent instances running out of memory?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a few requests that needs to use extensive amount of memory i.e. 40 MB more than other requests.
At the default of 10 max concurrent requests using a F1 auto-scaling instance, it can potentially use 400+  MB, which is way more than the 130MB-ish system memory it has available. There is no memory utilization setting in the yaml file, so I wonder what can be done to prevent such situations.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine don't have any memory utilization beside Python Garbage Collection.

My Advise is,

- Try to release memory as soon as response
- Try to optimize memory usage on that part, may be you need to use other service to help solving memory usage problem, eg. file serving via Google Storage, etc...
- Scale up instance to F2 which more suitable for production, but you still need to optimize your memory usage for higher usage.